# Get current User in MS Teams for Bots

Tags: email, active-directory, bots, microsoft-teams, toolkit

I have a general question about ms teams, bots and get current user values like email or ad id.

The background is a bot integrated in teams. He is for general working and send some json informations to the bot (not based on ms bots framework). I can see this in my bot. What I see is my name some crypted ids and some other values more or less senseless for me. I am working with ms teams toolkit first and I see no direct way to integrate other values to the initial bot chat.

I can't see my email address or my ad id. Which one I want have inside the the bot as value without any question for sending an email back to the user.

I read the docs from ms about messaging, but they are not very helpful.

My question: how can I integrate additional values from the current teams session like email device name into the initial bot chat?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what language you're using, but I'm presuming Node given that you're using Teams Toolkit. In your bot, inside the various event handlers, there's a `context` object. On that object, you can access `context.activity.from` which has things (for example):

```
    "from": {
        "id": "29:[some long id]",
        "name": "[user's name]",
        "aadObjectId": "[this is the user's Azure Ad Object Id]"
    },
```

So `aadObjectId` should match what you're looking for, "AD ID". To get the user's email, you need to make another call, as per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-single-member-details).

Comment: The point is, I am completly new to this items and world of MS. So I have no idea, that is and happens in the background.

Additional to this, my bot with teams integrated has an endpoint outside the MS world. I have a Cognigy bot (JS) as endpoint and here I got the JSON values in the input of the Cognigy bot.

So, what I need is the option to add the ad information in the first bot call. Follow your link, Fetching the roster or user profile / JSON, where is the place to add this? How make it variable with the aad-id?

Comment: Hi @Volker, Could you please refer this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot). It will help you.

Comment: @Sridevi-MSFT

The point is, after have a look inside the JS parts, the message handling for incoming messgaes is not the right place. I need (and search) for the place, where teams sends messages to my external bot. Here I need to add the ad data to send them into my Cognigy bot. 

Working (clicking) with MS toolkit, I see no direct way to do this and in the JS Scripts produced by the Tooklit I see no part, where the initial send happens.

Comment: @Volker, Do you want to send ad id to the bot as initial call or do you want to receive ad id from the bot as first response.

Comment: To send AD data from the bot as first response please add TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync() in OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync method. Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-single-member-details)